# Given a range of values between $a$ and $b$, what value should be represented by $50\%$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to figure out how to convert a percentage back to a number within a given set of values. Let's say the original values are between 1000 and 250. Somewhere between those values is a value $x$ that is at the $50\%$ point. How do I solve for x?

It is a little bit more complicated than I'm explaining, you're right. This relates to a slider on a touch screen. Given any range(a and b) that is input I need to: 1. find the percentage point of where the slider is on the line when the its dragged 2. then turn that percentage back into the number it represents. I've gotten part 1 down, it's part 2 I'm left with.

Update: Is this the correct way to solve the equation? 
[image]

Comment: I thought     a-b * c = x    would do it.

Comment: What do you mean by 50% point?  That half of the values are above and half below, or do you want the midpoint of the range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a uniform distribution and that $a>b$, you get
$$x=\frac{a-b}{2}+b$$

For any percentage $p$ this becomes
$$x=p(a-b)+b$$

Your answer should then be $x=625$ for the values $a=1000$, $b=250$, $p=0.5$.
In the solution you posted, you rounded your numbers which caused you to get the wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you want a linear (or "affine") relationship between the original set of values (call these $x$) and the scale that goes from $0\%$ and $100\%$ (call these $P\%$).

So you want to map $250$ (or more generally $a$) to $0\%$ and $1000$ (or more generally $b$) to $100\%$

The easiest way to map $250$ to $0\%$ is to subtract $250$ from the values. The transformation is $P=x-250$. Doing the same to $1000$, however, would map $1000$ to $750$. This is not the $100\%$ you were hoping for, so you need to apply another transformation. This second transformation can not be adding or subtracting as that will change the $0\%$ that you have just achieved. Therefore divide by $750$ and multiply by $100\%$.

The transformation is now $P=\frac {100(x-250)}{750}$.

Can you make this a more general formula? Hint: $750 = 1000 - 250$

To find the value of $x$ that will give $P\%=50\%$, you need to solve:

$$50=\frac {100(x-250)}{750}$$

Comment: There's no guarantee the distribution is  not skewed.

Comment: @Paul I agree - the questioner has left too much unsaid.

Comment: Bear with, I'm not highly skilled in math or communicating in mathematic terminology. I do appreciate the help. I've posted an update if that helps.

Comment: @spacemonkey Much better. I hadn't realised the orientation of your scale. Do you want the $0\%$ to be at $1000$ or at $250$?

Comment: To be at 250. The 0% will always be the lower number.